# How to create index files for a new language to support Find References of methods?

Tags: indexing, find-all-references

Suppose I have a datastructure of a filesystem that contains the basic information like the name, size & extension of all the files inside that directory. For every Directory & SubDirectory in my external harddrive, I have a program to create the above datastructure recursively(taking in mind that this is a time taking & IO Intensive process)

While creating the above datastructure, how can I also create some sort of index files which later helps me answer the below questions quickly(without reiterating the datastructures):

1. How many jpeg files are there in total?
2. How many files are there which are more than 1024KB?

It is basically creating Indexes on the FileName & Size property of the DataStructure.

Another paraphrase of the same question is how Eclipse/VisualStudio show the FindAllReferences of Methods/Variables. How are they maintaining `Eclipse-Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\*.index` files.